# Why doesn't my @property have an automatic getter?

Tags: objective-c

I've declared a property called Squad, but when I send [self getSquad] I get "no visible @interface for SquadViewController declares the selector 'getSquad'".

SquadViewController.h:

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "Squad.h"

@interface SquadViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *flipsidePopoverController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *squadNameLabel;

@property Squad *squad;

- (IBAction)updateTitleWithName:(id)sender;

@end
```

SquadViewController.m:

```
#import "SquadViewController.h"

@interface SquadViewController ()

@end

@implementation SquadViewController

@synthesize squadNameLabel;
@synthesize squad;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if (![self getSquad]) //<--THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
    {
        [self setSquad:[Squad squadWithName:@"New Squad"]]; //<-- NOT HERE, SO THE SETTER SEEMS TO EXIST
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

...
```

I thought that "@synthesize squad" would generate getSquad and setSquad, so I'm confused.

Here's the code for Squad, if for some reason that I don't get it's relevant (I'm new to Objective C, I still find it very confusing (I'm from a java background)):

Squad.h:

```
#import "SquadBuilderObject.h"

@interface Squad : NSObject

@property NSString *name;

+ (id) squadWithName:(NSString*)name;

@end
```

Squad.m:

```
#import "Squad.h"

@implementation Squad

@synthesize name;

+ (id)squadWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    Squad *newSquad = [[Squad alloc] init];
    [newSquad setName:name];
    return newSquad;
}

@end
```

Comment: Objective-C does not use the `get` prefix for anything but a very specific pattern.  You shouldn't prefix methods with `get` either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard getter for a property named `squad` is `squad`, not `getSquad`.

The "get…" nomenclature is typically reserved for things returned by reference (e.g. `- (BOOL)getSquad:(Squad **)outSquad`).

Comment: You also dont need to synthesize anymore

Comment: @waf - I kinda thought I didn't, but I put that in when it wasn't working.  So I just leave that out, and it does it automagically?  Do I not need to leave it in if I want compatibility with older versions of iOS?

Comment: @mazz0: Auto-`@synthesized` properties are a feature of the compiler, so as long as you're using a version of Xcode from the past couple of years, you get it for free. Since you need to have accessors for the property, it just gives them for free. If you want to do something besides the standard accessors, either you need to implement them yourself (in which case it won't synthesize anything you've already implemented), or if you're doing something really fancy with forwarding or whatever you can just declare it `@dynamic` and it won't synthesize in that case either.